# Why does copy and pasting a gigantic function not work

Tags: r, function, load

If I have some massive function in `R`, for example the `plot.modwt` function from the `wavelets` package, then I can't copy and paste the whole thing into console. It'll give error messages all the way through. But if I copy it chunk by chunk, then it'll work.

- Why does this happen?
- What is the solution to this (without copying the function to a script and loading it).

I am using the `R` console itself. It'll paste fine for about 100 lines then start showing `Error: unexpected...` at every second line.

```
plot.modwt <- function (x, levels = NULL, draw.boundary = FALSE, type = "stack", 
    col.plot = "black", col.boundary = "red", X.xtick.at = NULL, 
    X.ytick.at = NULL, Stack.xtick.at = NULL, Stack.ytick.at = NULL, 
    X.xlab = "t", y.rlabs = TRUE, plot.X = TRUE, plot.W = TRUE, 
    plot.V = TRUE, ...) 
{
    stackplot.modwt <- function(x, w.range, v.range, col.plot, 
        col.boundary, draw.boundary, X.xtick.at, X.ytick.at, 
        Stack.xtick.at, Stack.ytick.at, X.xlab = "t", plot.X = TRUE) {
        innerplot <- function(x, y, type = "l", xtick.at, ytick.at) {
            if (is.null(xtick.at) == FALSE || is.null(ytick.at) == 
                FALSE) {
                plot(x, y, type = "l", axes = FALSE, frame.plot = TRUE)
                if (is.null(xtick.at) == FALSE) {
                  axis(1, at = axTicks(1, xtick.at))
                  xtickrate <- xtick.at
                }
                else {
                  axis(1)
                  xtickrate <- par("xaxp")
                }
                if (is.null(ytick.at) == FALSE) {
                  axis(2, at = axTicks(2, ytick.at))
                  ytickrate <- ytick.at
                }
                else {
                  axis(2)
                  ytickrate <- par("yaxp")
                }
            }
            else {
                plot(x, y, type = "l")
                xtickrate <- par("xaxp")
                ytickrate <- par("yaxp")
            }
            tickrate <- list(xtick = xtickrate, ytick = ytickrate)
            tickrate
        }
        if (plot.X) {
            nf <- layout(matrix(c(2, 2, 1, 1), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE), 
                c(1, 2), c(2, 1), TRUE)
            par(mai = c(0.6, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6))
            if (x@class.X == "ts" || x@class.X == "mts") {
                x.range <- x@attr.X$tsp[1]:x@attr.X$tsp[2]
            }
            else {
                x.range <- 1:dim(x@series)[1]
            }
            tickrate <- innerplot(x.range, x@series[, 1], type = "l", 
                X.xtick.at, X.ytick.at)
            right.usrplotrange <- par()$usr[2] - par()$usr[1]
            NDCplotrange <- par()$plt[2] - par()$plt[1]
            marginpos <- (1 - par()$plt[2])/2
            right.usrlabelpos <- ((marginpos * right.usrplotrange)/NDCplotrange) + 
                par()$usr[2]
            text(right.usrlabelpos, 0, "X", xpd = TRUE)
            mtext(X.xlab, side = 1, line = 2)
            par(mai = c(0, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6))
        }
        if (plot.X == FALSE) {
            par(mai = c(0.4, 0.4, 0.1, 0.6))
            if (is.null(Stack.xtick.at) == FALSE) {
                xtickrate <- Stack.xtick.at
            }
            else {
                xtickrate <- NULL
            }
            if (is.null(Stack.ytick.at) == FALSE) {
                ytickrate <- Stack.ytick.at
            }
            else {
                ytickrate <- NULL
            }
            tickrate <- list(xtick = xtickrate, ytick = ytickrate)
        }
        if (is.null(w.range) == FALSE) {
            gammawave = wt.filter.shift(x@filter, w.range, wavelet = TRUE, 
                modwt = TRUE)
        }
        if (is.null(v.range) == FALSE) {
            gammascale = wt.filter.shift(x@filter, v.range, wavelet = FALSE, 
                modwt = TRUE)
        }
        if (y.rlabs) {
            rightlabels <- labels.modwt(w.range = w.range, v.range = v.range, 
                gammah = gammawave, gammag = gammascale)
        }
        else {
            rightlabels <- NULL
        }
        if (draw.boundary) {
            matrixlist <- list(modwt = as.matrix.modwt(x, w.range, 
                v.range), posbound = boundary.as.matrix.modwt(x, 
                w.range, v.range, positive = TRUE), negbound = boundary.as.matrix.modwt(x, 
                w.range, v.range, positive = FALSE))
            col <- c(col.plot, col.boundary, col.boundary)
            stackplot(matrixlist, y = NULL, y.rlabs = rightlabels, 
                type = c("l", "h", "h"), col = col, xtick.at = tickrate$xtick, 
                ytick.at = tickrate$ytick)
        }
        else {
            matrixlist <- list(modwt = as.matrix.modwt(x, w.range, 
                v.range))
            col <- col.plot
            stackplot(matrixlist, y = NULL, y.rlabs = rightlabels, 
                type = "l", col = col, xtick.at = tickrate$xtick, 
                ytick.at = tickrate$ytick)
        }
    }
    boundary.as.matrix.modwt <- function(x, w.range, v.range, 
        positive = TRUE) {
        if (is.null(w.range) == FALSE) {
            wavecoefmatrix <- array(NA, c(2 * dim(x@series)[1], 
                length(w.range)))
            Wjplot <- rep(NA, 2 * dim(x@series)[1])
            wavecoefmatrix.index <- 0
            W.Ljs <- ((2^w.range) - 1) * (x@filter@L - 1) + 1
            for (j in w.range) {
                wavecoefmatrix.index <- wavecoefmatrix.index + 
                  1
                if (positive) {
                  boundaryheight <- max(x@W[[j]])
                }
                else {
                  boundaryheight <- min(x@W[[j]])
                }
                leftspace <- rep(NA, 2 * (W.Ljs[wavecoefmatrix.index] - 
                  2 - vjH.modwt(x@filter@L, j, dim(x@series)[1])) - 
                  1)
                rightspace <- rep(NA, 2 * (vjH.modwt(x@filter@L, 
                  j, dim(x@series)[1])))
                middlespace <- rep(NA, 2 * dim(x@series)[1] - 
                  2 - length(leftspace) - length(rightspace))
                Wjplot <- c(leftspace, boundaryheight, middlespace, 
                  boundaryheight, rightspace)
                wavecoefmatrix[, wavecoefmatrix.index] <- Wjplot
            }
            rownames(wavecoefmatrix) <- seq(0.5, dim(x@series)[1], 
                by = 0.5)
        }
        if (is.null(v.range) == FALSE) {
            scalecoefmatrix <- array(NA, c(2 * dim(x@series)[1], 
                length(v.range)))
            Vjplot <- rep(NA, 2 * dim(x@series)[1])
            scalecoefmatrix.index <- 0
            V.Ljs <- ((2^v.range) - 1) * (x@filter@L - 1) + 1
            for (j in v.range) {
                scalecoefmatrix.index <- scalecoefmatrix.index + 
                  1
                Vj <- x@V[[j]][, 1] - mean(x@V[[j]][, 1])
                if (positive) {
                  boundaryheight <- max(Vj)
                }
                else {
                  boundaryheight <- min(Vj)
                }
                leftspace <- rep(NA, 2 * (V.Ljs[scalecoefmatrix.index] - 
                  2 - vjG.modwt(x@filter@L, j, dim(x@series)[1])) - 
                  1)
                rightspace <- rep(NA, 2 * (vjG.modwt(x@filter@L, 
                  j, dim(x@series)[1])))
                middlespace <- rep(NA, 2 * dim(x@series)[1] - 
                  2 - length(leftspace) - length(rightspace))
                Vjplot <- c(leftspace, boundaryheight, middlespace, 
                  boundaryheight, rightspace)
                scalecoefmatrix[, scalecoefmatrix.index] <- Vjplot
            }
            rownames(scalecoefmatrix) <- seq(0.5, dim(x@series)[1], 
                by = 0.5)
        }
        if (is.null(w.range) == FALSE && is.null(v.range) == 
            FALSE) {
            results <- cbind(wavecoefmatrix, scalecoefmatrix)
        }
        if (is.null(w.range) == FALSE && is.null(v.range)) {
            results <- wavecoefmatrix
        }
        if (is.null(w.range) && is.null(v.range) == FALSE) {
            results <- scalecoefmatrix
        }
        results
    }
    as.matrix.modwt <- function(x, w.range, v.range) {
        if (is.null(w.range) == FALSE) {
            wavecoefmatrix <- array(NA, c(dim(x@series)[1], length(w.range)))
            wavecoefmatrix.index <- 0
            for (j in w.range) {
                wavecoefmatrix.index <- wavecoefmatrix.index + 
                  1
                Wjplot <- x@W[[j]][, 1]
                Wjplot <- levelshift.modwt(Wjplot, wt.filter.shift(x@filter, 
                  j, wavelet = TRUE, modwt = TRUE))
                wavecoefmatrix[, wavecoefmatrix.index] <- Wjplot
            }
            rownames(wavecoefmatrix) <- 1:dim(x@series)[1]
        }
        if (is.null(v.range) == FALSE) {
            scalecoefmatrix <- array(NA, c(dim(x@series)[1], 
                length(v.range)))
            scalecoefmatrix.index <- 0
            for (k in v.range) {
                scalecoefmatrix.index <- scalecoefmatrix.index + 
                  1
                Vjplot <- x@V[[k]][, 1] - mean(x@V[[k]][, 1])
                Vjplot <- levelshift.modwt(Vjplot, wt.filter.shift(x@filter, 
                  k, wavelet = FALSE, modwt = TRUE))
                scalecoefmatrix[, scalecoefmatrix.index] <- Vjplot
            }
            rownames(scalecoefmatrix) <- 1:dim(x@series)[1]
        }
        if (is.null(w.range) == FALSE && is.null(v.range) == 
            FALSE) {
            results <- cbind(wavecoefmatrix, scalecoefmatrix)
        }
        if (is.null(w.range) == FALSE && is.null(v.range)) {
            results <- wavecoefmatrix
        }
        if (is.null(w.range) && is.null(v.range) == FALSE) {
            results <- scalecoefmatrix
        }
        results
    }
    labels.modwt <- function(w.range = NULL, v.range = NULL, 
        gammah = NULL, gammag = NULL) {
        verticallabel <- list()
        if (is.null(w.range) == FALSE && is.null(gammah) == FALSE) {
            for (j in 1:length(w.range)) {
                label <- substitute(paste(T^-gamma, W[level]), 
                  list(gamma = gammah[j], level = w.range[j]))
                verticallabel <- c(verticallabel, label)
            }
        }
        if (is.null(v.range) == FALSE && is.null(gammag) == FALSE) {
            for (i in 1:length(v.range)) {
                label <- substitute(paste(T^-gamma, V[level]), 
                  list(gamma = gammag[i], level = v.range[i]))
                verticallabel <- c(verticallabel, label)
            }
        }
        results <- verticallabel
        results
    }
    levelshift.modwt <- function(level, shift) {
        if (shift != 0) {
            level <- c(level[(shift + 1):length(level)], level[1:shift])
        }
        level
    }
    shift.modwt <- function(L, j, N) {
        Lj <- ((2^j) - 1) * (L - 1) + 1
        shift <- min(Lj - 2, N - 1)
        shift
    }
    vjH.modwt <- function(L, j, N) {
        Lj <- ((2^j) - 1) * (L - 1) + 1
        if (L == 10 || L == 18) {
            vjH <- (-Lj/2) + 1
        }
        else if (L == 14) {
            vjH <- (-Lj/2) - 1
        }
        else {
            vjH <- -Lj/2
        }
        vjH <- abs(vjH)
    }
    vjG.modwt <- function(L, j, N) {
        Lj <- ((2^j) - 1) * (L - 1) + 1
        if (L == 10 || L == 18) {
            vjG <- -((Lj - 1) * L)/(2 * (L - 1))
        }
        else if (L == 14) {
            vjG <- -((Lj - 1) * (L - 4))/(2 * (L - 1))
        }
        else {
            vjG <- -((Lj - 1) * (L - 2))/(2 * (L - 1))
        }
        vjG <- abs(vjG)
        vjG
    }
    if (type == "stack") {
        if (class(x) != "modwt") {
            stop("Invalid argument: 'modwt' object must be of class modwt.")
        }
        if (is.null(levels)) {
            w.range <- 1:x@level
            v.range <- max(w.range)
        }
        if (class(levels) == "numeric") {
            if (length(levels) == 1) {
                w.range <- 1:levels
                v.range <- max(w.range)
            }
            else {
                w.range <- levels
                v.range <- max(w.range)
            }
        }
        if (class(levels) == "list") {
            if (length(levels) < 1) {
                w.range <- 1:x@level
                v.range <- max(w.range)
            }
            if (length(levels) == 1) {
                w.range <- levels[[1]]
                v.range <- max(w.range)
            }
            else {
                w.range <- levels[[1]]
                v.range <- levels[[2]]
            }
        }
        if (class(levels) != "list" && class(levels) != "vector" && 
            class(levels) != "numeric" && is.null(levels) == 
            FALSE) {
            stop("Invalid argument: 'levels' must be numeric, vector, or list.")
        }
        if (plot.W == FALSE) {
            w.range <- NULL
        }
        if (plot.V == FALSE) {
            v.range <- NULL
        }
        if (plot.W == FALSE && plot.V == FALSE) {
            stop("At least one of plot.W or plot.V must be TRUE")
        }
        if (is.null(w.range) == FALSE) {
            if (min(w.range) < 1 || x@level < max(w.range)) {
                stop("Invalid argument: elements of 'levels' must be compatible with the level of decomposition of the 'modwt' object.")
            }
        }
        if (is.null(v.range) == FALSE) {
            if (min(v.range) < 1 || x@level < max(v.range)) {
                stop("Invalid argument: elements of 'levels' must be compatible with the level of decomposition of the 'modwt' object.")
            }
        }
        stackplot.modwt(x, w.range, v.range, col.plot, col.boundary, 
            draw.boundary = draw.boundary, X.xtick.at = X.xtick.at, 
            X.ytick.at = X.ytick.at, Stack.xtick.at = Stack.xtick.at, 
            Stack.ytick.at = Stack.ytick.at, X.xlab = X.xlab, 
            plot.X = plot.X)
    }
    else {
        stop("Only the stackplot is currently implemented.")
    }
}
<environment: namespace:wavelets>
```

Comment: Reproducible example please.  Try providing:  
1. The function you are trying to copy and paste  
2. The error messages you're receiving  
3. Some information about where you are copy/pasting this.  Are you using RStudio or the R console itself?

Comment: Save the function in a script file, and `source()` it... It will be much practical to edit and to run.

Comment: @juba I specified in the question that I want to copy and paste....

Comment: I wonder why you would want to do that ?

Comment: @juba Because it's quicker. `CTRL+A CTRL+V `is about 30 seconds less effort.

Comment: Can't reproduce your error.

Comment: @user2763361 if you do this multiple times, saving in a file and typing `source('/path/file.R')` is even faster.

Comment: Not necessarily, since I need to hold this in my brain as well as the task that I need to later delete it while I am thinking about 20 other stuff that I am modelling.

Comment: For those who can't reproduce this, it's because you're not using the same console as the OP.  See the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Despite your convictions that the way you're doing it is fastest and easiest,  it isn't.  Take the time to learn to use any of a large number of text editors which have direct links into R.  In that way, you don't even need to copypaste.  Just select the code and hit whatever keystroke or menu item passes the code into the R-console.

This can be done with EMACS, Notepad++ (with an external linking app), SublimeText 2/3, the builtin R.app GUI on OSX,  and many more.

Comment: I need to use console because I am programming a supercomputer.

Comment: But, great answer nevertheless and thanks for the software suggestions (I prefer Eclipse by the way).

Comment: At least one of those solutions (EMACS/ESS) allows the R process to be remote (running on a machine other than that which EMACS is running on, connected by telnet/ssh).

Comment: "Using a supercomputer" does not excuse you from learning to use the `source` function.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra suggested he use `source()` as a strategy an hour before he said he need to paste into the console because he was "using a supercomputer". (I have no idea what "these `software`" refers to.)

Comment: He wrote: "since I need to hold this in my brain as well as the task that I need to later delete it while I am thinking about 20 other stuff that I am modelling". I found that statement mostly incomprehensible and probably tangential to the issue at hand.